# how to set environment variable for all types OS?

Tags: java

I am developing a application in java. I need to set environment variable as some pre requisites for my application like database path, etc.

In OS i can able to set up manually, actually i need to set all my pre-requisites through java code, itself and also it should support all types of dektop platforms, preferably windows, linux and mac.

Comment: The environment variables are only needed during the execution of your application, right? Is there a reason you can't just use system properties or pass the necessary information to the code that needs it?

Comment: yes Thomas its right, but for few database access, i need to set envrionment variable path, similar to jdk path setting for development.

Comment: I believe it's not possible to set system environment variables from inside Java, except for child processes.

Comment: What database are you using? Are those environment variables really the only way to configure it? What are those variables in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to set a system environment variable from inside Java, except for a child process (ie, a process that gets launched by `ProcessBuilder`).

Each OS supports ways to change the user's default environment variables that are applied to new processes the user launches, but it depends on the OS. For example under Linux, it is often as simple as editing the file `~/.profile`, but not always (and I'm not a Linux pro to know all the ways). On Windows you'll want to edit the registry.

Answer (score 2):

I take it, that the Java Preferences API is out of the question due to not being able to manually edit it. *You could write your own settings editor however (command line app).*

Alternatively you could make a directory in `System.getProperty("user.home") + ".MyApp"`, that is in the user's home directory. Linux compatible, rights present. And then store a settings file there.